# Table with merged cells being read by power automate

Tags: excel, datatable, power-automate-desktop

[image: Table of sample data for the question]

I have a table in excel similar to the table shown. I need to use this Power Automate to read each row and put the column 1 row 1 into a specific text box on a MS form and then column 2 row 1 on its specific text box and same thing for the last column. I am able to do this if the cells are not merged and values repeat, however my actual dataset I need to do this in is large and that would be time consuming manually. I want it to be like

Text box 1: shirt
Text box 2: s
Text box 3: Blue

click submit and then submit another form

Text box 1: shirt
Text box 2: s
Text box 3: orange

click submit and then submit another form

Text box 1: shirt
Text box 2: L
Text box 3: Green

click submit and then submit another form

and so on till all data has been out in the form.

Is there a way to do this in Power Automate?

I already tried just regular read data and then make a table to input into the form, but it just places 0s in cells that if unmerged, would not have data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.